# Why is not lubuntu faster than kubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, performance

I made my first program at a big data course and profited to make a little study about the performance of my pc and my laptop, testing it in several systems and virtual images.

I found both computer slows down when the system has installations.

I expected to find lubuntu a bit faster than kubuntu but this is not what I found. I do not know basics of informatics and I wonder why so.

The result of the study was:

[image]

1, 2 and 3 are statical mean of the three methods of the program launching it 10 times. Total means total time executing the program 10 times.

My laptop has an i5 and 8Gb RAM, 250 GB disk

My pc has an i5 and 16GB RAM, 1TB disk

Comment: Without information about what these numbers mean, this question will be difficult to answer.

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are statical mean of three methods of the program launching it 10 times. Total means total time executing the program 10 times. I edit the question to explain it.

Comment: Programs do not automatically run faster on the same hardware when you use Lubuntu instead of Kubuntu. The only difference is that Lubuntu will use less resources (less memory etc.) than Kubuntu.

Comment: Why did you assume Lubuntu to be faster?

Comment: Which versions of Lubuntu and Kubuntu?

Comment: The introduction of the master installed lubuntu at a virtualmachine. So I said myself more ligth more efficient appropiated for big data. But after doing the test I am continuing to use ku in myboth computers. I realy don't know anything about how does a computer proccess data or what is the influence of the installed system.

Comment: Kubuntusys is 17.04. All the others are 18

Comment: By the way, Kubuntu 17.04 is no longer supported. You may want to upgrade to 17.10 (with support for a few more months) or to 18.04 which will be supported until April 2021.

Comment: I use to install the version suggested at the home page. I supose the diferent between 17 bussy and 18 virgin is more related with the status of the system. I should have installed 17 maybe but I deceided to profit to upgrade

Comment: At virgin test I even cutted wifi connection. I didn't touch baloo or other proccess.

Comment: I gave 1/2 of RAM memory in all the instalations at vbox and 2 cores cpu proccesor space dynami 10GB and always set minimal installation no downloads. Just installed pip3 matplotlib and tk and run de test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lubuntu and KDE are 2 Desktop Environments that both lie on top of a similar Linux Kernel.

Lubuntu is a lighter DE yes, meaning you have more resource left to have things open and better all round stability (resource wise)  but that doesn't mean it will run software's faster.

Comment: Unused RAM is wasted RAM =)